# Unit testing threads with dependency injection

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, dependency-injection, factory

I have a c# program that uses Castle Windsor for dependency injection. The program listens to a RabbitMQ queue.  In the thread that is created I call a class named FileProcessor which in turn calls another class named FileFixer.

I do not pass the container from Castle Windsor to the rest of the program.

How can I tell the program which implementation I am using in the bootstrapper so that I can create a new instance of a class that implements IFileProcessor and IFileFixer in the thread?

I was thinking of using a factory, but am not sure how to put it together.

Comment: How are you registering/instantiating IFileProcessor?

Comment: I will always recommend adding a factory to your container. Either an instance of a factory interface, or a `Func<IFileProcessor >`, whichever works better with your bootstrapper.

Comment: This question is heaps vague. What does `in the thread` has got to do with this? You need to add some code samples..